# ReactJs & React-Hook-Form: Display text input only when specific select list option is selected

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm working with `ReactJs` and `React-Hook-Form`. I have a component with a select list of car brands. When the component initially renders, I want the select list option to default to the value `Other`, and have a text input display so the user can input a brand that is not present in the select list. If the user selects an existing brand from the select list, then the text input should be hidden. Here is my code:

```
export default function Test() {
    
    type Car = {
        brandId: number,
        brand: string
    }

    const defaultBrandId = 5; // 'Other'
    const [showBrandInput, setShowBrandInput] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, getValues, watch} = useForm<Car>();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCarBrands();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        setShowBrandInput(getValues().brandId === defaultBrandId);
    }, [watch('brandId')]);

    function fetchCarBrands() {
        // API call to get select list data
        // Set default select list value to 'Other'
        setValue("brandId", defaultBrandId);
    }

    function onSubmit() {
        alert("form submitted");
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
                <Div className="mb-4">
                    <FormLabel>Brand</FormLabel>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Select {...register("brandId")}>
                                <option value="1">Chevy</option>
                                <option value="2">Ford</option>
                                <option value="3">Honda</option>
                                <option value="4">Toyota</option>
                                <option value="5">Other</option>
                            </Form.Select>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            {showBrandInput &&
                                <Form.Control type="text" {...register("brand")} />
                            }
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Div>
                <Button type="submit" className="btn-dk-blue">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </>
    )
}
```

The above code correctly initially renders with the default select list value `Other` selected and the text input is visible. If I then select a different value from the select list, the text input is hidden. My problem is if I then re-select `Other` from the select list, the text input does not get displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

this is a simple case of the wrong types being compared. The code above is **attempting to compare a string to a number** which is why it only shows on load. If you cast both as numbers in your use effect (or as strings) then the issue will be solved.

### Solution

Below is a working example of your code (with some modified HTML since I do not have the same components as you) **with both variables cast as integers** for correct comparison.

For details on changes and why they were made, see the bottom of this post.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function CarList() {
  type Car = {
    brandId: number;
    brand: string;
  };

  const defaultBrandId = 5; // 'Other'
  const [showBrandInput, setShowBrandInput] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, getValues, watch } = useForm<Car>({
    defaultValues: { brandId: 5 },
  });
  const CurrentBrandID = watch("brandId");

  const onSubmit = (data: Car) => {
    console.log("form submitted with data:", data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowBrandInput(+getValues().brandId === +defaultBrandId);
  }, [CurrentBrandID]);

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate id="carForm">
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label>Brand</label>
          <div>
            <select {...register("brandId")}>
              <option value="1">Chevy</option>
              <option value="2">Ford</option>
              <option value="3">Honda</option>
              <option value="4">Toyota</option>
              <option value="5">Other</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            {showBrandInput && <input type="text" {...register("brand")} />}
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn-dk-blue" form="carForm">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

### Changes:

1. Use effect is now checking if number 5 is equal to ids as a number. **by adding + symbol, we are casting them as integers**
2. **reordered placement of useEffects** as they should always come last or after the functions that they use or effect
3. Remove needed useEffect and setValue - this should be done **via useForm `defaultValue` object**

Comment: Works perfectly now, I appreciate your helpful answer!